# wikipedia page view statistcs

Tags: wikipedia

I need the page view statistics for any wikipedia page over certain time period. At least for one year. And they have to be in a certain format so that I can process them as json, xml or csv. I know that there are the page statistics by Domas Mituzas but they are too big. I only need page view statistics for some pages and not for all. Furthermore I have seen certain tools like http://stats.grok.se/ but here the period is not long enough (only 90 days).
Are there any other tools that provide the page view statistic in a format that can be processed?

Comment: The Domas's data seems to be sorted, so you might be able to use byte serving and binary search to get only the data you need.

Answer (score 1):

The stats.grok.se site contains data about more than just the last 90 days. You can get information about every month of a single page in JSON using a query like:

http://stats.grok.se/json/en/201106/Stack%20Overflow

Comment: Which time is used at the stats.grok.se? Is it UTC?

Comment: @user2523848 I *think* so, since that's the timezone Wikimedia wikis are on.

Answer (score 1):

- Open wiki page
- In a navigation menu to the left click "Page information" (Tools)

  [image: Wikipedia Page information]
- For some pages you may find page view statistics graphs here
- If not, scroll down to External Tools section
- Click "Page view statistics"

  [image: Page view statistics]
- You'll be taken to an external tool https://tools.wmflabs.org/pageviews where you can view statistics and download it as CSV, JSON, PNG.

  [image: Pageview Analysis, Cat vs Dog]

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is now out of date.

In 2016, responding to urging via the "Community Wishlist" process, the old stats.grok.se tool was replaced with the vastly improved [Pageview Statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wikipedia_Signpost/2016-11-04/Discussion_report%20%22%22) tool. (I'd post a direct link, but I don't have a high enough rep yet!) It's based on the same data as stats.grok was, as far as I know, but much more configurable -- arbitrary duration, multiple articles in one chart, etc.

- The tool may be found on the "view history" tab of any Wikipedia or Wikimedia article (in any language).
- Actual page views may be 50% higher than what's reported from the earlier days ([Signpost coverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wikipedia_Signpost/2014-09-17/News_and_notes%20%22%22))